# Turn off grid snap in simulink

Tags: simulink

In Simulink is there a way to disable grid snapping? And if so how is it done programmatically? I can't seem to find anything in their documentation about disabling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible.

Source: Co-worker

Answer (score 1):

As of Simulink R2013b (the only one I tested it on), there is a way. **View > Smart Guides** toggles on or off the snap feature.

There could be earlier versions that support this feature as well. I just don't have any earlier versions.